# Terraform AWS API Gateway with Proxy BadRequest Exception Invalid Mapping

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-api-gateway, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to create an aws proxy with terraform. I am currently stuck when applying the changes.
The error I get within the resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" is the following:

```
Error: Error creating API Gateway Integration: BadRequestException: Invalid mapping expression specified: Validation Result: warnings : [], errors : [Parameter name should match the following regular expression: ^[a-zA-Z0-9:._$-]+$]
```

Here is my code:

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "itemPutMethod-ApiProxyIntegration" {
  rest_api_id = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.apiGateway.id}"
  resource_id = "${aws_api_gateway_resource.itemResource.id}"
  http_method = "${aws_api_gateway_method.itemPutMethod.http_method}"

  type                    = "AWS"
  integration_http_method = "PUT"
  credentials             = "${aws_iam_role.s3_proxy_role.arn}"
  uri                     = "arn:aws:apigateway:${var.region}:s3:path/{bucket}/{folder}/{item}"

  request_parameters = {
    "integration.request.header.x-amz-meta-fileinfo" = "method.request.header.x-amz-meta-fileinfo"
    "integration.request.header.Accept"              = "method.request.header.Accept"
    "integration.request.header.Content-Type "       = "method.request.header.Content-Type"

    "integration.request.path.item"   = "method.request.path.item"
    "integration.request.path.folder" = "method.request.path.folder"
    "integration.request.path.bucket" = "method.request.path.bucket"
  }
}
```

And here is my code for the method:

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_method" "itemPutMethod" {
  rest_api_id      = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.apiGateway.id}"
  resource_id      = "${aws_api_gateway_resource.itemResource.id}"
  http_method      = "PUT"
  authorization    = "NONE"
  api_key_required = true

  request_parameters = {
    "method.request.header.Accept"              = false
    "method.request.header.Content-Type"        = false
    "method.request.header.x-amz-meta-fileinfo" = false

    "method.request.path.bucket" = true
    "method.request.path.folder" = true
    "method.request.path.item"   = true
  }
}
```

As far as I understand I have a bad character in the parameter names but I can't figure out where. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

API Gateway Resource

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "bucketResource" {
  rest_api_id = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.apiGateway.id}"
  parent_id   = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.apiGateway.root_resource_id}"
  path_part   = "{bucket}"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "folderResource" {
  rest_api_id = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.apiGateway.id}"
  parent_id   = "${aws_api_gateway_resource.bucketResource.id}"
  path_part   = "{folder}"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "itemResource" {
  rest_api_id = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.apiGateway.id}"
  parent_id   = "${aws_api_gateway_resource.folderResource.id}"
  path_part   = "{item}"
}
```

Link to tutorial code:
https://github.com/robty123/s3-proxy

Comment: Can you add the part of the code for the method?

Comment: Are you using `{proxy+}` path part in the API Gateway resource?

Comment: Are you sure that you have to use bucket ARN in `uri`? Not bucket https address nor S3 endpoint?

Comment: @MarkoE I dont. I specified 3 API Gateway Resources and each one of them has either a {bucket}, {folder} or {item} path part.

Comment: @Marcin Since I am only starting to learn AWS/Terraform my code is based on a tutorial and there they did use arn so I could probably try different approaches with bucket https address or S3 endpoint

Comment: Can you add the API Gateway resource block and the link to the tutorial if it's public?

Comment: Ok, so in the example there are three integration methods although one is a mock. Are you sure that the `itemPutMethod-ApiProxyIntegration` is the one causing the issue? Maybe GET is the one causing it? Also, as a side note: this code is almost 4 years old, it's never a good idea to use something that old to learn. :) And APIs have probably change a lot during that time period, so some of the calls might be wrong. And Terraform has seen major changes during that time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `request_parameters` argument in `aws_api_gateway_integration` resource have a space in one of the mappings. That seems to be the cause of failing regex match.

Change this

```
"integration.request.header.Content-Type "       = "method.request.header.Content-Type"
```

to

```
"integration.request.header.Content-Type"       = "method.request.header.Content-Type"
```